# What happens if I accept work contracts in two EU countries at the same time?

Tags: contract-law, european-union, health-insurance, ireland

I am going to accept a job in Dublin, Irealnd but I also have an opportunity of getting a work contract in the Czech Republic. The latter job would be mostly remote (it would require me to visit the Czech Republic from time to time) and I could manage having both of them.

I am an EU citizen. I am going to keep apartments in both countries.

1. Do I have to notify my employers about the situation? (There is no conflict of interest between these two posts.)
2. How about the health care? Can I use it freely in these two countries?
3. Would this situation lead to pension problems in the future?

Comment: Great question. Alas, #2 and #3 are completely outside my area of expertise and while I could take a stab at #1 I'll leave that to someone with more expertise in that area than I as well.

Comment: How could any of that matter? Despite your belief that there is none, why would you not cover your back by explaining to both employers how there is no conflict of interest?

Doesn't whether you can use health care in either or both countries depend on your contracts?

Doesn't whether this situation could lead to pension problems in the future depend on the contract details?